# jcitest matlab interpretation of output

Tags: matlab

I am using the matlab function for the Johansen test [jcitest to estimate a VECM](https://de.mathworks.com/help/econ/estimate-vec-model-parameters-using-jcitest.html). As far as I understood, the output corresponding to the cointegration vector here is the `B` stored in `paramVals in mles,` while the intercept is `c0`:

```
A(B´yt−1+c0)
```

When using the function [egcitest for the Engle-Granger test](https://de.mathworks.com/help/econ/estimate-vec-model-parameters.html), I get 1 value less for B and add a 1 to the cointegration vector, since the first coefficient is normalized to unity.
Does this mean that in the output of jcitest, the first coefficient is not normalized, but rather the first value stored in `B`?
And if so, is there any way to also normalize this cointegration vector such that the first value is 1?

Comment: Moved the question to [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/jcitest-matlab-normalization-of-cointegration-vector)